# Look up transformation is SSIS is not sending Error data rows into file, Why?

Tags: ssis

I have started working with SSIS recently and I am hit a dead end with the look up transformation error rows redirect to a file. I have configured to send the rows that do not have a match to a flat file destination. But the file will not contain the collumn data, which is blank however the error code and error collumn into the text file.

This is the data contained in the text file:

,-1071607778,0

,-1071607778,0

,-1071607778,0

The first position suppose to be the data in my field but seems like its blank for a reason i don't understand. Any body help me clarify this, What am i missing???

Comment: Is the field being looked up in your data blank?  You can set up a data viewer on the link before the lookup to inspect what's going on.

Comment: My data was not blank. But thanks for taking the time i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that looks like the error number, not the row data